# Different Carbonation Levels on a Single Manifold

Tags: kegging, pressure

I have a Belgian Golden Strong and an American Brown that are both going into the same keggerator that share the same manifold.  I would like to carbonate the Belgian at a higher value than the American Brown, but I am not sure how to maintain this level of carbonation with the shared manifold.  It does have valves on each port so i can switch if needed, but I am looking for a "set it and forget it" method.

I typically set my CO2 pressure at about 20 and rock the keg for about 3-4 minutes then seal it off and let it sit for 24 hours or so to get the initial carbonation, but I don't understand (at least) two things:

1.) How can i really control the CO2 level for each in the initial carbonation and

2.) How can i maintain the proper levels after the initial carbonation with a shared manifold.  Even if i get a separate regulator to allow a lower pressure on some beers, I have been led to believe that serving pressure is around 5-10 psi, and i don't see logically how a set psi can maintain variable levels of carbonation.

I do have one gas line on the manifold that is shorter (approx 3 feet) than the others (each approx 5 feet), so suppose I may be able to get close from what I understand about psi vs. gas line length, but I am looking for a more authoritative answer than "that might do what I want".

Any ideas/feedback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll answer your questions out of order. To get different CO2 pressures, you need separate regulators. You can do it in two ways: I use a dual primary, [like this one from Micro-Matic](http://www.micromatic.com/draft-keg-beer/regulators-pid-642-Battery.html).

[image]

Your other option is to have [one or more secondary regulators](http://www.micromatic.com/draft-keg-beer/regulators-pid-8022.html) after your manifold or instead of a manifold.

[image]

For #1, in my opinion the best way is to just set it and forget it, instead of the high-pressure shake method. First you would find the appropriate volumes of CO2 for your two beers (let's say 2.4 for the Belgian and 2.0 for the Brown). Then, [using a carbonation chart like this one](http://knoxhomebrewer.com/images/stories/Reference/carbonation%20chart.pdf), find out the pressure you need to keep on the kegs at the temperature in your fridge. I keep my fridge at 37-41F, so averaging that to 39F my pressures would be 7 and 11 PSI (those numbers seem a little low in my experience, so some experimentation may be needed).

Now in order to dispense without foam, you need to [balance your lines](http://beersmith.com/blog/2011/07/14/keg-line-length-balancing-the-science-of-draft-beer/). This means using appropriate serving line lengths and diameters to provide enough resistance to prevent foaming, but enough freedom for a good pour. Again, this may require some experimentation. In my system, I have 6', 3/16" diameter lines and serve and carbonate at 10-11 PSI. You can even find calculators online, [like this one](http://www.iancrockett.com/brewing/info/kegbalance.shtml).